# How to link a lot of C++ object files without using too much memory?

Tags: c++, memory, compilation, linker

I am writing a C++ program that uses a lot of data internally. This data is distributed over roughly 5000 source code files. When I run *make*, all these files compile to object code flawlessly. However, when I want to link everything together into one executable my computer runs out of memory.

- How can I split this task into smaller ones? Is it, for example, possible to link a subset of the object files into another object file and therefore reduce the number of object files that need to be linked in the end?
- Where can I learn on how to set up a compilation process of very large projects?

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use static libraries to compile submodules of your code, or you can use larger swap-files.

Comment: You should divide you large app to app and some dynamic linked libraries. Or just add RAM to your computer :)

Comment: You can place the data into a separate file and then read the file at run-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile your code into a static library. Then compile against the library which should include only what you need in the final executable.

If you are working with GCC take a look at the AR options. Static library is an archive which you can combine and extract as needed.

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful.